# Navigate to another url in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am passing href value from my model to the view and changing the href code like this:

```
<p><a href="@item.source" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Facebook</a> </p>
```

but its url is showing like this on another page

```
http://localhost:1333/naat/facebook.com
```

How to correct that code?

Comment: You need to prefix links with `http://` or the browser treats them as local.